# Keep getting an unexpected token k in JSON at position 0 when sending a python request

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

There is this game API I'm trying to develop a client for, and sending a PUT request to change the profile pic (even with the same structure as the games source code) returns an `unexpected token k in JSON at position 0`, the code I used is below:

```py
with open("img.jpg", "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    bytess = str(bytearray(f))

imageParam = {
    "key": "profile_image",
    "data": bytess,
    "filename": "profilepic.jpg",
    "mimeType": "image/jpg"
}

newUrl = "https://bwsecondary.ddns.net:8080/api/v1/current_user/profile_world"

Confirm = requests.put(newUrl, data=imageParam, headers=headers)
print(Confirm.text)
```

It isn't the server since the game doesn`t receive the error when making a put request

Answer (score -1):

Ok so, I had to parse it as Json instead of data, which is a rookie mistake, oh well...